# delta method with $ \frac{1}{n} \sum (X_{i} - \bar{X})^{2} $

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let independent $X_{i} \sim N(\mu, \sigma^{2})$ and $S_{n}^{2} = \frac{1}{n} \sum (X_{i} - \bar{X})^{2} $ (I do not mean $\frac{1}{n-1}$)

I ultimately want to find the following: 
What does $\sqrt{n}(log(S_{n}^{2}) - log(\sigma^{2}))$ converge in distribution to?

My attempt: 
I've so far shown that $S_{n}^{2} \rightarrow \sigma^{2}$ in probability and thus in distribution. Thus, $\sqrt{n}(S_{n}^{2} - \sigma^{2}) \rightarrow N(0, Var(S_{n}^2))$ but I'm having a hard time figuring out what $Var(S_{n}^2)$ is... I heard it is related to $E[X_{i}^{4}]$

Comment: You heard right!  Do you know of any connection $S_n$ has with the $\chi^2$ distribution, by any chance?

Comment: Hmm if I remember correctly, $\frac{n}{\sigma^2}S_{n}^{2} \sim \chi^{2}_{n-1}$?

Comment: So you possibly/probably  also remember the formula for the variance of a $\chi^2$ distribution.

Comment: So $Var(\frac{nS_{n}^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}) = Var(\chi^{2}_{n-1}) = 2(n-1)$ so $var(\frac{1}{n}\sum (X_{i} - \bar{X})) = \frac{2(n-1)\sigma^{4}}{n^2}$... But how do I get $E[X_{i}^{4}]$ out of this?

Comment: So the variance of $S_n^2$ is$2(n-1)\sigma^4/n^2$, according to what you wrote, which is asymptotically $2\sigma^2/n$ which is all you need for your delta method calculation.  The $2$ in the formula you recited incorporates the result of a calculation of  $EX_1^4$.  (The table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments can help you, but is not needed.)

Comment: So then we have $\sqrt{n}(log(S_{n}^{2}) - log(\sigma^{2})) \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sigma^2}N(0, 2\sigma^2/n)$ by the delta method. However, I am being told the solution is $\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sqrt{E[X_{1}^{4}]}N(0, 1)$ which is equivalent to $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}N(0, E[X_{1}^{4}])$.. unless the book has an error (which is possible)

Comment: Whoops, mean to say $\sqrt{n}(log(S_{n}^{2}) - log(\sigma^{2})) \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sigma^2}N(0, 2\sigma^4/n)$